# create custom page for user profile tab in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I'm working on a WP site and have come across a issue, in which I'm confused. So here's my trouble :

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/user/<username-variable>/posts
```

Now for each user there will be this unique url as given above, with `<username-variable>` which will be dynamic as the name implies, so my question is how do i create page for this URL ?

I tried to create one right now but it keeps on telling that page not found. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you rewritten the URL?

Comment: No I haven't. Please guide me with how do I do it here for WP. I've used URL rewriting for my core php projects but not for WP.  @spudmonkee

Comment: tamare .htaccess file ma change karvo padse

Comment: I know that for url rewrite I should make change in .htaccess but my confusion is about to what URL should i point the rewritten URL ? do you know of some good sample explaining this ?

Comment: please tell me in gujarati

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/222680/18731) answer could help you, from there you can figure it out what you have to do.

Comment: you have to create rewrite rule for your own URL with custom page.Check this this out.https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: @all i already have a page created for url till : http://localhost/mywebsite/user/<username-variable>/   but i want a separate page created for this : http://localhost/mywebsite/user/<username-variable>/posts